# Call to undefined method pdo::prepare

Tags: php, mysql, object, pdo, instance

I'm writing a registration script for a website and tested the code with the function databaseConnection in the registration.php script, everyting worked but now I replaced the databaseConnection function to a seperate file so I dont have to type the same code again every time.

I took the instance from the database from the databaseConnection.php file and loaded it into the private variable $db_connection in registration.php, now I want to prepare the connection for a sql statement but the script returns error ' Call to undefined method DatabaseConnection::prepare()'

This is the databaseConnection.php script

```
<?php
class DatabaseConnection {
//private zodat niemand een nieuwe kan maken
private static $instance = null;
//constructor private zodat niemand instantie kan klonen
private function __construct(){
    try{
        $this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $exception){
            $this->errors[] = $this->lang['Database error'];
        return false;
    }
}
public static function getInstance(){
    if(self::$instance === null)
        self::$instance = new DatabaseConnection();

    return self::$instance;
}
}
?>
```

I loaded the instance into $db_connection in my __construct function in registration.php like this

```
$this->db_connection = databaseConnection::getInstance();
```

Now my code crashes on the $check_user_name=... line

```
...
        } else if ($this->db_connection != null){
        $check_username_query = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:user_name OR user_email=:user_email'); 
...
```

Can someone help me solve this error? I read the similar questions on stackoverflow but couldn't figure it out with the information given in there.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message more carefully:  'Call to undefined method **DatabaseConnection**::prepare()'

Your `DatabaseConnection::getInstance()` returns an instance of `DatabaseConnection` instead of `PDO`. One possible solution would be implementing [`__call()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) in `DatabaseConnection` or extending `PDO` like Chris Barrett said.

Comment: I did a var_dump of $this->db_connection in registration.php. This is the result:object(DatabaseConnection)#2 (1) { ["db_connection"]=> object(PDO)#3 (0) { } }. This does not look like a PDO object if i'm correct?

Comment: @Gijs No, as the beginning states it is a `DatabaseConnection` object (that contains a `PDO` object)

Comment: now I added a __call method into the databaseConnection.php en i'm getting past the prepare() line, but now i'm stuck at the next, where I try to add the variables with bindValue() with $check_username_query->bindValue(..); This means i successfully gave my instance to the db_connection variable?

Answer (score 0):

$this->db_connection is DatabaseConnection object not a PDO object I think. Prehaps you want to extend the PDO object for example:

```
class DatabaseConnection extends PDO {
```

Otherwise you could declare wrapper functions around PDO for the methods you would like to call.